# XSL-FO filesize

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I'm generating multiple PDF documents with XSL-FO using FOP in .NET. 
The file size seems just to double each n PDF-pages and I wonder why. 
I'm generating the multiple document with the for-each(node) statement in my xsl dokument and the pages looks, except for some words, the same (multiple Online Tickets). 
This is my result for the file size of some of this PDF documents:

```
PDF-Pages | Filesize(KB)
--------------------
  1          183
  3          183   
  5          183
  7          366
  9          366
 11          366
 13          366
 26          732
```

Maybe anyone has an idea, why the size of the PDF output looks so strange?

Comment: So the measurements are PDF file size, not XSL FO file size?

Comment: Yes. File size of XSL-FO output PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

PDF file sizes vary since they are compressed. The filesize output from XSL-FO can change greatly depending on the many configuration settings:

- PDF version
- tagged PDF
- Fast Web view PDF
- graphic resolution
- graphic quality
- black & white/color
- encryption